# Can't convert my timespan difference to any of the custom ones

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
                    DateTime a = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["user_lastlogin"]);
                    DateTime b = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan diff = b - a;
                    Label3.Text = diff.ToString();
```

This is what I do, not sure if this is the optimal solution but I'm still learning.
This what shows up in Labe3

```
                    00:20:41.8159296
```

How could I make it to for example only

```
                    00:20:41
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom time-format string to achieve the format you want.

```
Label3.Text = diff.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

(also see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) for more formatting options)

Comment: @Maximilian_Gerhardt  Thanks, works like a charm. I self been trying doing weird stuff with String.Format("{0:T}", dt); but it did not went too well.

Comment: Something that should also have worked is accessing the `Hours`, `Seconds` and  `Minutes` property of the `TimeSpan` object itself, e.g. `Label3.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);`, but the right format string is faster and clearer :)

Comment: @Harugawa `String.Format` could work. You just needed the correct format string (`string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", diff);`).

Answer (score 0):

Here you got a good reference.
[Timespan Formating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Answer would be:** (Timespan to HH:mm:ss formated)

```
new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

(make sure not use hh instead of HH because 0 can be printed out as 12 (depend on your local culture settings))

Comment: This is not an answer, it's at best a comment.

Comment: OP seems to need the seconds also